# show ajax success or error message when form is submitted on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got the messege to apear in the DIV tag but not sure how to send the email address onto the external email database //myguestlist.com/mgl/formreceiver.php.

**here is the HTML**

Be the first to know about the Channel Seven Brisbane Racing
                  Carnival:

```
              method="post" id="mf528c0a39d76be"> <input class="mailchimp-input"

                input="" name="PatronEmail" id="mf528c0a39d76be_PatronEmail"

                placeholder="Enter your email..." type="text"> <button type="submit"

                class="btn"><span class="singup-image"><img src="img/send.png"

                    alt="send email"></span><span class="singup-text">Send</span></button>
            </form>
            <div class="success-message"></div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
          </div>
```

**Here is the PHP:**

```
<?php
```

// Email address verification

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]]).)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]).){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

```
// Enter the email where you want to receive the notification when someone subscribes
$emailTo = 'wbriton@brc.com.au';

$subscriber_email = ($_POST['PatronEmail']);

if(!isEmail($subscriber_Email)) {
    $array = array();
    $array['valid'] = 0;
    $array['message'] = 'Insert a valid email address!';
    echo json_encode($array);
}
else {
    $array = array();
    $array['valid'] = 1;
    $array['message'] = 'Thanks for your subscription!';
    echo json_encode($array);

    // Send email
$subject = 'New Subscriber!';
$body = "You have a new subscriber!\n\nEmail: " . $subscriber_email;
    // uncomment this to set the From and Reply-To emails, then pass the $headers variable to the "mail" function below
//$headers = "From: ".$subscriber_email." <" . $subscriber_email . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $subscriber_email;
mail($emailTo, $subject, $body);
}
```

}

?>

And here is the Java Script

$('.success-message').hide();
    $('.error-message').hide();

```
$('.subscribe form').submit(function() {
    var postdata = $('.subscribe form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/sendmail.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.valid == 0) {
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').html(json.message);
                $('.error-message').fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.subscribe form').hide();
                $('.success-message').html(json.message);
                $('.success-message').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log(json.message)` ?

Comment: Forgive me but im not really a coder, where abouts to i put that?

Comment: How come you can code like that if you're not coder? Put `console.log(json.message)` inside your if(json.valid == 0) and inside `else` and when you use chrome press f12 and check your `console `